# Combine two numpy arrays into matrix with a two-argument function

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

Roughly I want to convert this (non-numpy) for-loop:

```
N = len(left)
M = len(right)
matrix = np.zeros(N, M)
for i in range(N):
  for j in range(M):
    matrix[i][j] = scipy.stats.binom.pmf(left[i], C, right[j])
```

It's sort of like a dot product but of course mathematically not a dot product. How would I normally vectorize or make something like this pythonic/numpythonic?

Comment: It's `np.zeros((N,M))`.  And better to index with `arr[i, j]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`scipy.stats.binom.pmf`** already is vectorized.  However, you have to **`broadcast`** your inputs in order to get your desired result.

```
broadcast_out = scipy.stats.binom.pmf(left[:, None], C, right)
```

---

***Validation***

```
np.random.seed(314)
left = np.arange(5, dtype=float)
right = np.random.rand(5)
C = 5

broadcast_out = scipy.stats.binom.pmf(left[:, None], C, right)

N = len(left)
M = len(right)
matrix = np.zeros((N, M))
for i in range(N):
  for j in range(M):
    matrix[i][j] = scipy.stats.binom.pmf(left[i], C, right[j])

print(np.array_equal(matrix, broadcast_out))
```

```
True
```